# Puppet manifest ordering fails due to depndency cycle

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to achieve "top to bottom" execution of steps defined in my manifest.

```
define ui_deploy::ui_deploy_manifest( $deploy_params, $params ) {

$version = $deploy_params['version']
$install_dir = $deploy_params['install_dir']

file { "$install_dir/unzip-ui.ps1":
    ensure => present,
    content => template('ui_deploy/unzip.erb')
}

exec { "unzip_ui":
    path => 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0',
    command => "powershell -executionpolicy remotesigned -file ${install_dir}/unzip-ui.ps1",
    require => File["$install_dir/unzip-ui.ps1"],
    logoutput => true
}

file { "thirdparties":
   path => 'D:\teamdeploy_install_dir\ui',
   source => 'D:\teamdeploy_install_dir\thirdp',
   recurse => true,
   require => [
                Exec["unzip_ui"],
                Anchor["after-com.team.project.project-thirdparty"],
              ]
}

file { "$install_dir/msbuild.bat":
   ensure => present,
   content => template('ui_deploy/msbuild.erb'),
   require => File["thirdparties"]
}

exec { "run_msbuild":
    command => "cmd.exe /c ${install_dir}\\msbuild.bat",
    path => $path,
    require => File["$install_dir/msbuild.bat"],
    logoutput => true
}}
```

During manifest parsing it fails with

> Puppet (err): Could not apply complete catalog: Found 1 dependency cycle:
>   (Exec[unzip_ui] => File[thirdparties] => File[D:\teamdeploy_install_dir\ui/unzip-ui.ps1] => Exec[unzip_ui])

I really can't understand where is the cycle here. From my point of view it is dependency chain but not a loop. Please show me where I'm wrong with this.
I also tried to rewrite it on 'before' statements but result is the same.

Comment: `Anchor["after-com.team.project.project-thirdparty"],` appears to be the offending parameter. Test removing it and let me know what happens.

Comment: The code you presented does not explain the cycle.  Specifically, it does not explain the dependency expressed as `File[thirdparties] => File[D:\teamdeploy_install_dir\ui/unzip-ui.ps1]`.  If what you present is in fact the locus of the resource declarations that are involved in the problem, then one or more additional relationships are being declared by other means -- either via in-scope resource defaults, or via a collector-based resource override.

Comment: Note also that the problem appears to be detected during catalog application, not manifest parsing (a.k.a. catalog building).

Comment: @JohnBollinger there is missing information here, but I think it is safe to assume that `File[D:\teamdeploy_install_dir\ui/unzip-ui.ps1]` is coming from `file { "$install_dir/unzip-ui.ps1":` and `$install_dir = $deploy_params['install_dir']`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, yes, I have also supposed that `File[D:\teamdeploy_install_dir\ui/unzip-ui.ps1]` comes from the declaration you reference.  But the relationship between that `File` and `File[thirdparties]`, cited in the error message, does not come from anything in what was presented.

Comment: Yes. @MattSchuchard is right about variable resolution.  Anyway rewriting on `notify => subscribe` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting on `notify => subscribe` statements solves this problem.